# How do I preload web fonts when using vuejs and veutifyjs with vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, preload, vue-cli-3

I have a web app that I created with vuejs and veutifyjs. 
When a do a pagespeed insight, I get a very low performance and the suggestions are that I should preload some CSS files and web fonts. I can change the rel of css files but I don't know how to change that of web fonts.
Here's an image of the suggestion.
[image]

Comment: If you are loading Roboto from Google then you should be doing it with `<link>` inside your `public/index.html` - and thus it is easy to add the `preload` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in two ways:

1. Add `<link>` of your font inside along with `preload` attribute.
2. Let `service-worker` to handle the caching mechanism, that would include `.woff` fonttype as well.

Comment: I'm using a service-worker to load fonts and css. Everything is working very fine. Just that the result of pagespeed is very low. 11%

Comment: Pagespeed and web.dev were little bit strict overall. But i just focus on my metrics on Lighthouse built-in Chrome/Edge. I would say the site as least as reliable as my clients' feedbacks told.